# How to fill names with NA based on a different column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I fill the second column with NaN if the first column has NaN?

I tried this

```
df1.type2.fillna(value=df1.type1, inplace=True)
```

input

```
,type1,type2
2020-01-02 6:00,NaN,ABC
2020-01-02 12:00,NaN,DEF
2020-01-02 18:00,60,GHI
```

output

```
,type1,type2
2020-01-02 6:00,NaN,NaN
2020-01-02 12:00,NaN,NaN
2020-01-02 18:00,60,GHI
```

Comment: print('AFTER:',data.isnull().values.any())   # prints False now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df.loc[df.type1.isna(), 'type2'] = np.nan
```

Or [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with default value `NaN`, so not necessary set:

```
df['type2'] = df['type2'].mask(df.type1.isna())
print (df)
                  type1 type2
2020-01-02 6:00     NaN   NaN
2020-01-02 12:00    NaN   NaN
2020-01-02 18:00   60.0   GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
>>> df.type2.where(df.type1.notna(),inplace=True)
>>> df
         Unnamed: 0  type1 type2
0   2020-01-02 6:00    NaN   NaN
1  2020-01-02 12:00    NaN   NaN
2  2020-01-02 18:00   60.0   GHI
```